# How to nest my own "times" function to get powers

Tags: functions, functional-style, recursion

I have a "times" function.  I'd like to create a power function using it.  It should look like this for an 6th power:

`times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, x]]]]]`

I can't seem to figure out how to use Nest to get this.  I'd like to create my power function to be something like p[x,n].

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer, so: `With[{n = 5}, (Composition @@ ConstantArray[times[x, #] &, n])[x]]`.

Answer (score 11):

```
Nest[Times[#, x] &, x, 5]
```

or

```
Nest[# x &, x, 5]
```

or specifically for your `times` :

```
Nest[times[x, #] &, x, 5]
```

> ```
> times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, x]]]]]
> ```

Comment: @MitchellKaplan I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

```
Fold[times[#2,#1]&,1,Table[x,{6}]]
```

This assumes your times function still leaves times[x,1] to be x.

Comment: Nowadays, of course, one can do `ConstantArray[x, 6]` in place of `Table[x, {6}]`.

Comment: ah, sorry, I'm old school (have been hooked since v2.2, 1993).

Comment: No prob. I've been using it since version 2.2 also, and I still find myself slipping into old habits every so often...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your "times" is associative, here's another more 'efficient' variation:

```
Clear[power];
power[b_, 1] := b;
power[b_, 0] := 1
power[b_, n_Integer] := 
  With[{h = power[b, Quotient[n, 2]]}, b~times~h~times~h] /; Mod[n, 2] == 1;
power[b_, n_Integer] := 
  With[{h = power[b, Quotient[n, 2]]}, h~times~h] /; Mod[n, 2] == 0;
```

This recursively splits the product into squares of half the power.  In action:

```
power[x, 6]
```

> `times[times[times[x, x], x], times[times[x, x], x]]`

Why might this be better?  Consider:

```
times[a_, b_] := (count++; a b);

count = 0; {power[x, 250], count}
count = 0; {Nest[times[x, #] &, 1, 250], count}
```

> `{x^250, 12}`
>
> `{x^250, 250}`

`times` is only evaluated 12 times in this scheme compared to 250 times in the simple approach.  For the same effort we could do:

```
count = 0; {power[x, 2^250], count}
```

> `{x^1809251394333065553493296640760748560207343510400633813116524750123\
>   642650624, 250}`

Answer (score 3):

How about a recursive definition?

```
power[b_, n_] := b ~times~ power[b, n - 1]
power[b_, 0] := 1

power[x, 5]
```

> ```
> times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, times[x, 1]]]]]
> ```

Comment: nice, +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Just for variation and to add a little visual clue,

```
Attributes[Tpower] = {HoldFirst};
Tpower[x_^y_] := Fold[times[#2, #1] &, 1, ConstantArray[x, y]]
```

Gives:

```
Tpower[4^9]
```

> times[4, times[4, 
>     times[4, times[4, 
>       times[4, times[4, times[4, times[4, times[4, 1]]]]]]]]]