# Iterative Function Mapping

Tags: functional-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest my own “times” function to get powers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/how-to-nest-my-own-times-function-to-get-powers)

What I want to do is something like :

```
Sin[...Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[x]]]]]
```

Basically, defining a function that maps a said function on an argument said number of times.

Comment: Take a look at `Nest` and `NestList`. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html Don't forget to check `NestWhile`,`NestWhileList`, `FixedPoint`, `FixedPointList`. And this tutorial: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsRepeatedly.html

Comment: You can do e.g. `Nest[Sin, x, 5]`, look at this  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/how-to-nest-my-own-times-function-to-get-powers

Answer (score 4):

I get an easy one !!

```
Nest[Sin,x,10]
Out[8]= Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[Sin[x]]]]]]]]]]
```